# How to get Datasheet view working on Macintosh system?

Tags: 2010, datasheet, mac-os-x

How to get Datasheet view working on Macintosh system. Even many other features are not working on Safari browser. So is there any way to get it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to get the Datasheet view working in Safari.

SharePoint Joel has [a great matrix](http://www.collabshow.com/2012/03/14/sharepoint-browser-support-matrix/) of which features work in which browser.

Answer (score 5):

Datasheet view requires an ActiveX control not available for that platform.  See [Plan browser support (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is the better route for Mac users.  But even with Firefox, datasheet won't work as Trevor said, it's an Active X component.  The alternative is to use Parallels on the Mac system and give them a Windows environment with IE.